# NXLog - Input txt file with date on the end

Tags: configuration, logstash, nxlog

I am currently trying to send a log file with NXLog to a remote server. I have this working correctly. My next challange is that the date changes on the log file daily. For example on day one it would say log.20170110 and the day after it would say log.20170111. I would like my NXLog configuration to be able to have a date variable at the end of log. is this possible. My current configuration is below.

```
 define ROOT C:\Program Files (x86)\nxlog
Moduledir %ROOT%\modules
CacheDir %ROOT%\data
Pidfile %ROOT%\data\nxlog.pid
SpoolDir %ROOT%\data
LogFile %ROOT%\data\nxlog.log

<Extension syslog>
 Module xm_syslog
</Extension>

<Input in>
 Module im_file
 File 'C:\Temp4\log.20170104.txt'
 SavePos TRUE
</Input>

<Output out1>
 Module om_tcp
 Host 10.10.10.10
 Port 5166
</Output>


<Route 1>
 Path in => out1
</Route>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

SG

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should work for that:

```
File 'C:\Temp4\log.*.txt'
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use the `strftime` function to generate a formatted date string.  It at appears the format string you want to use is %Y%m%d.

So that would look like this

```
File 'C:\Temp4\log.' + strftime(now(), '%Y%m%d') + '.txt'
```